# what is csrss exe in windows xp, and can I delete it?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, task-manager

I'm trying to figure out what are all processes working right now in the task manager of my computer (Windows xp).

I'm wondering what does *csrss.exe* actually does and if **I can get the rid of it without making the computer crash...?**

(First time asking here :) )

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You may have been downvoted because the question shows a lack of research effort. Did you try googling the file and seeing what information is available? If you did do any research, let us know what you found and what you are having trouble understanding.

Comment: That is good to know @MC10. I thought having an answer in Super User was good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `csrss.exe` is a normal Windows component put there by Microsoft.   The process assists in the implementation of many user-mode functions in Windows, notably in the Windows User Interface.

It’s perfectly safe and is supposed to be there. In fact, if you manage to kill it or it otherwise dies, your system will blue-screen or hang.

### Could csrss.exe be infected with something?

Although fairly uncommon, there have been some who’ve reported problems with their `csrss.exe` becoming infected or impersonated by malware (malicious software).  Here’s a few ways which might help you determine if you’ve got an issue on your hands:

1. Prior to Vista there should only be one `csrss.exe` running in the system. In Vista and later there is one for each session. There is one session for the "boot session" (this where e.g. services, lsass, etc. run) and one for each logged-in user. On a typical Vista or later system where you have just one logged-in user, i.e. no one has done "fast user switching", then you should have two `csrss` processes. If you see additional processes running `csrss.exe` it then the extra processes running are likely a virus / malware.
2. If the CPU usage of `csrss.exe` reaches 100% it’s experiencing an
   error of some sort. Right-Click `csrss.exe` in the Task Manager,
   then Select *End Process*.  Windows will not allow you close the
   process if it’s the real thing since `csrss.exe` is a protected
   component.

If you’re running task manager in an elevated prompt **you will be able to close critical system processes**, this could crash your computer and force a restart so be careful and make sure any open document has been saved.

Comment: I tried to close it in XP and it also don't allow me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a critical system process or a trojan.

You have to check its location to confirm. If it's under **Windows/System32** then it's a system process otherwise it's a trojan and should be deleted.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Is there a way to search the location from the task-manager?

Comment: @PabloGomez Yes. Right click on the process and check properties for location.

Comment: @Mohi That's not available with WinXP Task Manager.